# How to consume or use the HTTPS contained URL of a webservices from different server location to aspx page ??

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, wcf-security

I had created a web service with https secured . Buts i cant consume the service inside my aspx page. If i use http is is responding and working normally . When i use https secure web service it throws exception like this , mentioned below

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="www.santext.mobi"'.  "

How to solve this kind of issue

Comment: Thank you.. I solved this issue.

Comment: Please do add your solution to this question, if any unlucky should should stumble upon this question in the search for truth (or solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The solution is just add https:\ to your url that the service is going to be consumed. Then you wil receive the methods from that service.